# What is the best practice to send password from android app to REST webservices?

Tags: android, web-services, rest, bcrypt

In Spring I used bcrypt. I would like to know what are the best practices to send passwords from android app to Web services

1. Password shouldn't be visible explicitly in URL
2. Password should be encoded (may be salted) [how to decode them in web services code]

Comment: *"how to decode them"* - you can't, the whole point of salting and hashing is that it's one-way. There appears to be at least one Java implementation of bcrypt, have you looked into that?

Comment: I have used it without looking into its details. Based on Zaph's answer, if I send the password with encoded in POST, won't it make less secure??

Comment: There's discussion on that here: http://security.stackexchange.com/q/53594/72084

Answer (score 0):

Use HTTPS, everything except the address portion of the URL will be encrypted.

Passwords should not be hashed by the client.

It is best to send them in a post, URL query strings are many times written to server logs. – zaph 2 mins ago    edit